# Import path issues when trying to use a template's components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-2019

I have a React template that I downloaded and I'm attempting to move part of its assets, components, containers, etc. over to my project (Visual Studio 2019 React Application) to make it look like the template. I thought this would be a better learning exercise than just modifying the template (the template is pretty big too and I don't want my project to be populated with too many unused content).

So I have this script (`src/reducers/Settings.js`) in my project (same location as in the template) which refers to another file as such:

```
import {
  CHANGE_DIRECTION,
  CHANGE_NAVIGATION_STYLE,
  DARK_THEME,
  DRAWER_TYPE,
  FIXED_DRAWER,
  HORIZONTAL_MENU_POSITION,
  INSIDE_THE_HEADER,
  SWITCH_LANGUAGE
} from 'constants/ActionTypes';
```

I do have a `ActionTypes.js` file in `src/constants`.

But when I try to run the application, I get this error saying the application failed to compile

> ./src/reducers/Settings.js
>       Module not found: Can't resolve 'constants/ActionTypes' in 
>       'C:\path\ClientApp\src\reducers'

But all of this is working fine in the template itself and I'm pretty sure the physical file/folders structure is the same.

If I change the import statement to import from `/constants/ActionTypes` it works but there's a lot of these scripts that will come from the template and I certainly don't want to have to go through modifying them all.

Is there a config in my app that would allow resolution to work properly without modifying the template's import statements?

Comment: Why not using VSCode or one of the recommended IDEs?

Comment: @DennisVash All of my controllers will be C# .NET Core controllers, will I be able to debug that using another IDE than VS? And will this fix the problem at hand?

Comment: It will fix the React part, about the .NET I dont know

Comment: @DennisVash The template runs fine in a Visual Studio solution. So I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Did you make sure you copied all your index files over as well? Also, are you using your template as an njsproj in visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I missed a file to transfer over from the working template project.

`jsconfig.json` had this which made absolute paths work

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "paths": {
            "@/*":["src/*"]
        }
    }
}
```